LONGBLOB in Spring Data JPA
I am working on a project where I have a table with images. I need to store image as LONGBLOB. Application is implemented in Spring Boot and MySQL database should be generated when application is started. Is there any way to specify LONGBLOB in Spring Boot?
Right now I am using @Lob annotation but that generates column with type of TINYBLOB.
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class ImageEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_image")
    private Integer idImage;
    @Basic
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image",nullable = false)
    private byte[] image;
    

}


I managed to find a solution, just added type definition in @Column annotation. There is no need for @Lob annotation.
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class ImageEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_image")
    private Integer idImage;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "image",nullable = false, columnDefinition="LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] image;
}

